# Count number of first layer/set of children in cloned element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to count the number of it's first layer of children **not including it's child of child of child..** This is my codes

HTML

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="btn-container col-md-12">
      <a href="#">Hello</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

JS

```
$('a').click(function(){
    var c = $(this).closest('.row').clone();
  $(this).after( c );
  var count = $(this).closest('.row').find('.btn-container').length;
  alert(count);
});
```

The alert should always return 1 since the cloned element is appended inside of it.

[image]

[**jsFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/kfcr45zt/)

**I tried ..**

`.find()` but also as I expected, it will count all inside of it.. Child of child of child and so on...

```
var parent = $(this).closest('.row');
var count = $('.btn-container', parent).length;
```

But still can not get what I want.

I already think of adding a name/class specifying to them. Like `btn-container first-children` ..

But I am wondering if there is a jQuery trick that will make it simplier.

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/children/ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than `find()` you could use `children()`. From jQuery `.children()` [documentation](https://api.jquery.com/children/):

> The .children() method differs from .find() in that .children() only
>   travels a single level down the DOM tree while .find() can traverse
>   down multiple levels to select descendant elements (grandchildren,
>   etc.) as well

```
var count = $(this).closest('.row').children('optional-selector').length;
```

Comment: Yes It works. Thanks. I did not know that there is such thing as `.children()` in jQuery. I made it by doing this `$(this).closest('.row').children('.btn-container').length;`

Comment: @rmondesilva Yes, you can add an optional selector for children to filter the kind of children it selects. I will update my answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

`find('.btn-container')` will select all descendants `.btn-container`. You should use direct child selector `>` like following.

```js
$('a').click(function () {
    var c = $(this).closest('.row').clone();
    $(this).after(c);
    var count = $(this).closest('.row').find('>.btn-container').length;
    //---------------------------------------^^--------------------
    alert(count);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="btn-container col-md-12">
      <a href="#">Hello</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Oh. I never thought using `>` inside `.find()` function is possible. +1 to you.  It works but I found a simpler answer.